# System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem cannot be used as a parameter value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using mvc 5 for which i am problem in insertion for dropdownlist selected list

**My View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NatureofLeave, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-6" })
    <div class="col-sm-6 pushleft">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NatureofLeave, ViewBag.EmployeeLeave as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-Select-")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NatureofLeave, "", new { @style = "color:red;" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Model:**

```
[Display(Name = "Type of Leave")]
public List<SelectListItem> NatureofLeave { get; set; }
```

**My Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Leaves(EmployeeLeave objEmpLeave)
{
    objEmpLeave.NatureofLeave = BindDataFromDatabaseToLeave();

    var selectitem = objEmpLeave.NatureofLeave.Find(p => p.Value == objEmpLeave.NatureId.ToString());

    if (selectitem != null)
    {
        selectitem.Selected = true;
        ViewBag.Message = "NatureofLeave " + selectitem.Text;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objEmpLeave.StartDate.ToString()))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Please provide start date");
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objEmpLeave.EndDate.ToString()))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "End Date is calculated by startdate... So, make sure start date is not empty!");
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objEmpLeave.NatureofLeave.ToString()))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Select one");
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objEmpLeave.Reason))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Reason cannot be empty");
    }

    else
    {
        objEmpLeave.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userId"]);
        objEmpLeave.UserName = Convert.ToString(Session["name"]);

        int leaveID = objIAccountData.InsertLeave(objEmpLeave);

        if (leaveID > 0)
        {
            TempData["msg"] = "<script>alert('Your Application has been sent')</script>";
        }

        else
        {
            TempData["msg"] = "<script>alert('Something went wrong to send the application')</script>";
        }
    }
    return View(objEmpLeave);
}
```

I am using Dapper ORM so i will give you the repository.

**My Repository:**

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyString"].ToString()))
{
    var param = new DynamicParameters();
    param.Add("@UserId", objEmployeeLeave.UserId);
    param.Add("@UserName", objEmployeeLeave.UserName);
    param.Add("@StartDate", objEmployeeLeave.StartDate);
    param.Add("@EndDate", objEmployeeLeave.EndDate);
    param.Add("@LeavesAvailed", objEmployeeLeave.LeavesAvailed);
    param.Add("@NatureofLeave", objEmployeeLeave.NatureofLeave);
    param.Add("@Reason", objEmployeeLeave.Reason);

    param.Add("@UserIdOut", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

    con.Open();
    con.Execute("sprocInsertLeaves", param, null, 0, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    int UserIdOut = param.Get<int>("UserIdOut");
    con.Close();
    return UserIdOut;
}
```

Actually, the problem is in the repository located at the dropdownlist 
`param.Add("@NatureofLeave", objEmployeeLeave.NatureofLeave);`

So, anyone can solve this problem....
Thanks in advance

Comment: `List<SelectListItem>` is a collection, so that you may need iterate through to get its text/value first (only recognized `struct`-based value types & `string` allowed to use as parameter value).

Comment: You view code makes no sense. A `<select>` posts back a single value (it cannot be bound to a `List<SelectListItem>)`. Your `NatureofLeave` property needs to be `int` or `string` or whatever the type is that you use for the option values.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Hello sir, can it possible to have int or string for a dropdownlist.... Can you explain me

Comment: Of course (and it needs to be). The `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property is for the 2nd parameter of the `DropDownListFor()` method - i.e. the the property which displays the options (which in your case is `ViewBag.EmployeeLeave`)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, I can;t understand sir

Comment: Sorry I Can't..

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding

First you need to fill the NatureofLeave not the EmployeeLeave

Second in case you have Model in the page you need no ViewBag

Third you are not filling the ViewBag with EmployeeLeave

This Code:

```
return View(objEmpLeave);
```

is filling the model and not the ViewBag

why not to use below if you are declaring the model at the TOP of the View Page since the Model would be EmployeeLeave:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NatureofLeave, Model.NatureofLeave, "-Select-")
```

Here better to Use:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyString"].ConnectionString
```

Since you are using:

```
using (SqlConnection con = 
new SqlConnection(
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyString"].ToString()))
```

No need at all to:

```
con.Close();
```

since dispose will close and clean since dispose is calling close inside it

Last Thing it's recommended to:

Try not to use ViewBag unless you are forced to

For inserting Multiple Data:

Read how to work with Tables Relation One (Named Parent) => To Many (Named Child)

To Insert In Parent Then Another Command to Insert in Child